# Create multiple Excel workbooks from a master file and the files must use an existing template with mutiple worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

Stuck in a loop actually. I have a master data sheet containing thousands of rows.

1. The first challenge is that I need to transfer specific data from a master workbook to a pre-defined template.
2. The second challenge is to create multiple workbooks based on cell data.
3. The third challenge is to create multiple worksheets in the workbooks created in challenge 2.
4. The fourth challenge is to save the workbooks automatically in a specific folder.

Attaching the pictures for better understanding

[The master sheet data from where data would be extracted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8P7J.jpg)

[The form which has to be populated multiple times. Areas are marked where data has to be transferred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsHQu.jpg)

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Check on here: many posts with code about moving from, or to, master file.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: That's a big ask, and I feel like you getting in over your head, at least a bit. Take a look at the link below, and try to do some of these things yourself, because it's just too much to do in one single go. Then, post back when you get stuck with very specific things. 

https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/section3.htm

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps that might work

1. You can obtain a predefined Template via Record Macro option. Then you can use filter option to transfer the desired data to the Template
2. You can create as many excel workbooks based on your cell data by segregate  using if(), select case() and nested ifs(), if needed.
   you can also use logical functions like AND(), OR() and XOR() etc., inside your if statements.
3. Its just a consolidation work and the codes are readily available
4. Its under consolidation